# Method to return Http Status Code with Generic deserialized value

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I am writing a method to get the de serialized result from a `HttpClient` call as below

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string clientName, string resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var client = ConfigureHttpClient(clientName);
    return await client.GetFromJsonAsync<T>(resource, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}

private HttpClient ConfigureHttpClient(string clientName)
{
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient(clientName);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["HttpClientSettings:Timeout"]));
    return client;
}
```

Now I want to return `HttpStatus` code form the method as well. Something like below

```
public async Task<(T,HttpStatusCode)> Get<T>(string clientName, string resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var client = ConfigureHttpClient(clientName);
    var result = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<T>(resource, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    //return something like below
    return(result, result.Statuscode)
}
```

but not sure how to get the status code form it.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to use `GetAsync` method and from that get the response and status code. Using extension method that ditches the status code and only care about the result won't work.

Something like:

```
public async Task<(T,HttpStatusCode)> Get<T>(string clientName, string resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var client = ConfigureHttpClient(clientName);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(resource, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    return (content!, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following ready to use class wraps the standard `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` and supports generic usage:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class HttpClientWrapper
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public HttpClientWrapper(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<Result<T>> GetAsync<T>(string requestUri, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            try
            {
                string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUri, ct);
                T? obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
                return new Result<T>(obj);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                return new Result<T>(ex.StatusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Log the exception.
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    class Result<T>
    {
        public Result(T? value)
        {
            Value = value;
            StatusCode = null;
        }

        public Result(HttpStatusCode? statusCode)
        {
            Value = default;
            StatusCode = statusCode;
        }

        public T? Value { get; }
        public HttpStatusCode? StatusCode { get; }
    }
}
```

Please note that

1. `GetAsync()` method returns the deserialized object and a `null` `HttpStatusCode` if the HTTP call succeeds.
2. `GetAsync()` method returns a `null` deserialized object and `HttpStatusCode` if the call throws an `HttpRequestException`.
3. I *do not* prefer using tuples in public APIs since tuples are more appropriate for internal implementation, hence I defined the `Result<T>` class.

You may make an objection to the `GetAsync()` method since *it returns HTTP status code only when the HTTP call fails*. For me this is no problem since normally I will not be interested in the status code when the HTTP call is successful. If you insist on returning the status code even when the call is successful then this is certainly doable.